# New R session: Global environment full (RStudio)

Tags: r, global-variables, environment

Whenever I start a new R session via RStudio, my global environment is full.

I know that

```
rm(list = ls())
```

removes all globals in a current working environment; but, upon restarting RStudio, these same variables are now in the global environment again.

Why is this the case? How can I delete these variables permanently?

Comment: There is a file `.RData`, which is loaded by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @jogo, you have an `.RData` file in your working folder. Remove it. Then, uncheck the box of `Restore .RData into workspace at startup`. This is my setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am using MacOSX, so I had to navigate to Files > .RData, select it, and then click Delete.